# How to find all the elements in the following html using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<div class="summary-number-lg ng-binding" name="ib-summary-revenue"> $ 248 </div>
```

I need to validate if the summary revenue is `$248` or not.

Is there any way to validate the name and the value? 
And how to select them using find elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the element, for example, *by name* and assert its text. Example in Python:

```
summary_revenue = driver.find_element_by_name("ib-summary-revenue")
assert summary_revenue.text.strip() == "$ 248"
```